# ERROR: The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Join<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>'cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

```
var result =  new ReviewRequestDecisionModel
            {
                Decision = await  repo<FOTreeDetailsEntity>().Queryable().Where(s => s.OperActivityID == OperActivityId)
                .Join(_untracked<FOTreeDetailsDocsEntity>(),
                                    s => s.Id, c => c.TreeDetailsLineID, (s, c) => new { decision = c })
                 .Join(
                        _untracked<DecisionReasonTypeEntity>(),
                        d => d.decision.DocStatusTypeID,
                        s => s.Id,
                        (d, s) => new { decisionD = s })
                 .Join(
                        _untracked<FOTreeDetailsDocsStatusEntity>(),
                        m => m.decisionD,
                        n => n.FOTreeDetailsDocs,
                        (m, n) => new DecisionModel
                        {
                            DecisionStatusId = n.DecisionReasonTypeID,
                            DecisionStatusTypeName = m.decisionD.HebName ,
                            Reasons =  m.decisionD.Reasons != null ? m.decisionD.Reasons.Select(r => new ReviewDecisionReasonModel
                            {
                                HebName = m.decisionD.HebName,
                                Id = n.DecisionReasonTypeID,
                                Remark = n.TechRemark,
                                FreeTextAllow = m.decisionD.AllowFreeText

                            }).ToArray() : new ReviewDecisionReasonModel[0],
                            ActivityTypeId = (int)aType,

                        }).FirstOrDefaultAsync()
            };



public class ReviewRequestDecisionModel
    {
        public virtual DecisionModel Decision { get; set; }
    }

 public class DecisionModel
    {
        public string DecisionStatusTypeName { get; set; }
        public int? DecisionStatusId { get; set; }
        public int? ActivityTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual ReviewDecisionReasonModel[] Reasons { get; set; }
        public UploadedFile ReviewSumFile { get; set; }
    }
```

This code cause error because of the last join. the error means:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Join<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(IEnumerable, IEnumerable, Func<TOuter, TKey>, Func<TInner, TKey>, Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

why I can't use abstract class? what important to me is the join between the tables and not the classes. Thank you!!

Comment: Why `join` instead of navigation properties?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks, it helped me. you can write it as an answer :)